# How to fix the error: "CS0012 The type 'Task' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. "

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

It's very strange that the projects are built successfully, but got this error in Visual Studio 2015:

> Error CS0012  The type 'Task' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Threading, Version=1.0.2856.102, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Here are what I do:

1. I create a Class Library Project (.Net Core) in VS2015 Update3, named `Library`, and change the `project.json` as follows:

   ```
   {
     "version": "1.0.0-*",
     "frameworks": {
       "net35": {
         "dependencies": {
           "TaskParallelLibrary": "1.0.2856",
           "AsyncBridge.Net35": "0.2.0"
         }
       },
       "net40": {
         "dependencies": {
           "Microsoft.Bcl.Async": "1.0.168"
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   `Library` is multi-targeting net35 and net40, and depends on a few packages so that we can use `async` and `await` in net35 and net40.
2. Add class `Foo`:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Threading;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   namespace Library {
       public class Foo {
           public async Task Bar() {
               await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                   Console.WriteLine("bar");
               }, new CancellationTokenSource().Token);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create another Class Library Project (.Net Core), named `SomeApp`, with the `project.json`:

   ```
   {
     "version": "1.0.0-*",
     "dependencies": { "Library": "1.0.0" },
     "frameworks": {
       "net35": {
         "dependencies": {
           "TaskParallelLibrary": "1.0.2856",
           "AsyncBridge.Net35": "0.2.0"
         }
       },
       "net40": {
         "dependencies": {
           "Microsoft.Bcl.Async": "1.0.168"
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   `SomeApp` is referencing `Library`.
4. Add class `App` in `SomeApp` project:

   ```
   using Library;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   namespace SomeApp {
       public class App {
           public async Task DoWork() {
               var foo = new Foo();
               await foo.Bar();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   `App` is calling `Foo.bar()`.

**It's able to built both projects, and there are nothing wrong during the compilations**, but if you click the `App.cs` in `SomeApp` project in Solution Explorer in VS2015, the error appears in the Error List:

[image]

So how do i fix the error? And is this a bug of Visual Studio?

Comment: Have you tried adding it like it suggests?

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic I cannot add the dll manually in the project.json, but only can add a dependence. However, after adding a dependence on "TaskParallelLibrary": "1.0.2856" to `SomeApp`, New error comes out: 
_Error CS0433 The type 'Task' exists in both 'System.Threading, Version=1.0.2856.102, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' SomeApp..NET Framework 4 c:\Users\jarenduan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Library\src\SomeApp\App.cs_

Comment: Task class is part of .Net 4.0, so theroretically, I shouldn't need referencing another Task class. And the tricky thing is that you don't get the CS0012 error when you only have one library, the error appears in the 2nd project which referencing the first library.